# Zooming in with dragging and making an area

Tags: adobe-illustrator, zoom

I'm watching a guide on Youtube about Illustrator and they seems to select an area and zoom in there, but if I do that I select an object. Also, he uses the 2015 CC version, meanwhile I'm using the 2018 CC one.

Comment: https://youtu.be/wRL9rPO2SYk?list=PLYfCBK8IplO4X-jM1Rp43wAIdpP2XNGwP&t=114     Btw, there is the feature I was talking about.

Comment: He's using the zoom tool, as far as I can tell.  Another way is to select an object, and zoom in using CTRL++.  Or another way is ALT+centre scroll wheel (on a mouse).

Comment: Nope, i wanna zoom in exactly like he does. He selects an area and zooms right there in the spot

Comment: He's using the zoom tool, by clicking and holding down the mouse button while dragging with the tool.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to hover to the Preferences > Performance then tick "Animated Zoom" under the GPU Performance.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Zoom tool - on toolbar at left: looks like an old-fashioned magnifying glass.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm not adding much to what has already been said by other people, but there's still room for clarification.

You say that when you do it, it selects an object, but with the Zoom tool that is only possible if you hold down modifier keys, which you're not supposed to do. The other option I can think of is that you're trying to zoom using the Move tool or something.

I feel like the guy in the video did say it pretty clearly:

> "With the Zoom tool active, you can click and drag to select an area to zoom into."

Except that it might not work like that depending on your settings. This click and drag zoom that is shown in the video is the original way PS used to zoom when clicking and dragging. I believe it was Photoshop CS5 that introduced `Scrubby zoom`, which makes the click and drag zoom work sort of like a slider (<sub><sup>click+drag to left = zoom out **&** click+drag to right = zoom in</sup></sub>) and this scrubby zoom should be on by default.

If you want to zoom the way shown in the video, you should **make sure "Scrubby zoom" is unchecked** in the Zoom tool options at the top.

[image]

Should be noted that you obviously can't draw a box to zoom out. If you try to do that it works just like clicking.

---

---

You should also know that there are are these two shortcuts combinations you can use to toggle the zoom tool functionality with virtually any tool active, so you don't have to be switching tools when you want to zoom.

- Zoom in: `Cmd+Space` *<sub><sup>(Replace Cmd with Ctrl on Windows)</sup></sub>*
- Zoom out: `Cmd+Alt+Space` *<sub><sup>(Replace Cmd with Ctrl on Windows)</sup></sub>*

These shortcuts work with virtually any tool active and they behave exactly the same as if you were using the Zoom tool.

So you could have like the Brush tool active, hold down `Cmd+Space` and click & drag in the document to zoom in.